# AS3 Object moves to random location within stage onClick

Tags: actionscript-3, object, random

I'm trying to make an object, a red circle move bounce to a random location within my stage onCLick, and display the message `you touched my circle`. I don't quite know what i'm doing wrong.

Here is what i came up with

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

myCircle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  trace("you touched myCircle");
  Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+High-Low))+Low;
}
var High = stage.stageWidth == 550, stage.stageHeight == 400;
var Low = stage.stageWidth == 0, stage.stageHeight == 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var HighH:int=stage.stageHeight;
var HighW:int=stage.stageWidth;
var LowH:int=0; var LowW:int=0;
....
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("you touched myCircle");
myCircle.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighW-LowW))+LowW;
myCircle.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighH-LowH))+LowH;
}
```

You need to set your circle's new coordinates, use `x` and `y` properties for that.

Comment: That was a very quick response. Thank you! It's working perfectly now.

Comment: Please use "tick" to say that this answer is what you needed.

Comment: Small addition: Variables in actionscript should start with a lowercase, only classes should start with an uppercase.